# (Java) How to loop through the content of an array?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, and have been following step-by-step guides online.
However, I was unable to run this chunk of codes though I followed exactly what was taught and I got compile time errors.

my code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] family = {"Tricia", "ALbert", "Edwin"};
    for(String name = family) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope could get some guidance here to show me where went wrong. I also notice I'm very bad with symbols and special characters.

I'd appreciate a lot for your help and precious time. Good day.

Comment: Please include code and errors in the **text** of your question. Don't post them as links and/or screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enhanced For Loop - Array of Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530699/enhanced-for-loop-array-of-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java for loop syntax: "for (T obj : objects)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763131/java-for-loop-syntax-for-t-obj-objects)

Comment: Also, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))` to print the array. It is in the standard library.

Comment: Sorry, first time using Stack Overflow here. Will keep that in mind, @khelwood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for this kind of for loop is

```
for(String name : family)
```

Instead of what you have

```
for(String name = family)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @NAMS, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

use the "enhanced for loop":

```
for(String name : family) {
     // do stuff with name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible ways:

1.-

```
for(String name : family) {
     // do stuff with name
}
```

2.-

```
final int len = family.length;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
         System.out.println(family[i]);  //where family[i] is the string at the give index
         // do stuff with name
    }
```

Comment: **3. -** Precalculate the array length so not to calculate it at each iteration: `int l = family.length; for ... < l ...` **4. -** Use the inverse loop (from l to 0; i--), because it's faster (it seems that subtracting is faster than adding)

Comment: That is a very good one!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.

```
for(int i =0; i < family.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(family[i]);
}
```

This will loop through the array and what ever the value of `i` is, will be the index of the array that is printed.

IE: index [0] is "tricia", index[1] will be "Albert" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements of an array in a couple of ways.

**1. Standard for loop**

```
for(int i = 0; i < family.length; i++){
  System.out.println(family[i]);
}
```

This is a standard for loop that iterates through each element of the array and prints each value.

**2. Enhanced for loop**

```
for(String value : family){
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

This is what you were trying to do in your sample, but you had `=` instead of `:`

Both work the same way to get the values of the array